# how to show the title on mouse over and hide the image in the same div, jquery and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Mainly, i am using Bootstrap on my website
I want to **hover the mouse** on image ,that represents an article, and show the title of the article and the image will hide.
**on mouse leave** will hide the title and appear the image
Please can anyone help?

### Html

```
<div class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" >
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" >
        <?php displayData('sumbola','1','image'); ?>    
        <div class="carousel-caption hide">
            <h3 ><?php  displayData('sumbola','1','title'); ?></h3>
            <a href="labels.php?id=1">Διαβάστε<br>περισσότερα.</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JQuery

//show the title of the article

```
$(".item").on('mouseenter',function(){ // if mouse-over the icon then the title will show up 
$(".carousel-caption").removeClass("hide");
$(".imglabel").addClass("hide"); // and the image will hide
});

$(".item").on('mouseleave',function(){
$(".carousel-caption").addClass("hide"); //if the mouse leave, then the image will appear again
$(".imglabel").removeClass("hide"); //and the title will leave
});
```

Comment: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/02/3-cool-css3-image-hover-effects/ try this example

Comment: http://callmenick.com/post/image-overlay-hover-effects-with-css3-transitions

Comment: @Vishal thank you for the link.
I will check out the hover effects they look usefull!

Answer (score 0):

Use hover and add attribute "display:none" which is a lot easier than the method you are using:

```
$(".item").hover( function(){
 $(".carousel-caption").attr("display","block");
 $(".imglabel").attr("display","none");
},function(){
 $(".carousel-caption").attr("display","none");
 $(".imglabel").attr("display","block");
})
```

one other thing is that you should use IDs here preferably in my personal opinion. thus instead of (".item") you can use ("#ItemID") for example to set a specific action for each different item you have.

Comment: it seems reasonal but it doesn't work. |
The id it applies only for one tag and i want a method for all items i have :)
Many thanks for the quick response!!

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with the above code, Does anything happen? DO you have anything in dev tools?

Comment: I hover and nothing is happening. With my code the image disappears and appears really fast. In both codes the title doesn't show.